# Numpy best way to assign array to a single point in another array (4D)

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing, python-xarray

I would like to store each one of the arrays (new_grid) at a given cell on another array (master_grid), which varies according to i and j:

`master_grid[i][j]=new_grid`

When I run the code it returns the following error for the above line:

```
<ipython-input-233-e449b6b2f1a1> in <module>
     16         new_grid=coordinates_within_radius(coords_ref, coords_grid, radius)
     17 
---> 18         master_grid[i,j]=new_grid

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I'm using both numpy and xarray, but so far couldn't figure out a way of indexing the "inner" arrays into the `master_grid`.

As it can be seen in the code, there is a function that determines which points are within a radius and the result is a grid with latitude and longitude.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import seaborn as sns
import geopy.distance

 ### Code for locating points within a radius        
def coordinates_within_radius( coords_ref, coords_grid, radius ):
    if type(coords_grid) == np.ndarray or type(coords_grid) == list:
        new_grid = [coords_grid[i] for i in range(len(coords_grid)) if geopy.distance.distance(coords_ref, coords_grid[i]).km < radius]
    else:
        if geopy.distance.distance(coords_ref, coords_grid).km < radius:
            new_grid=coords_grid;

    if len(new_grid) == 0:
        print('the grid is empty')

    return new_grid

storm=[1,2,3,4]
date_time=[1,2,3,4,5]
radius=500
scale_lat=6
master_grid=[]

for i in range(len(storm)):
    for j in range(len(date_time)):
        coords_ref = [30, -80]
        lon = np.arange(coords_ref[1] - scale_lat,coords_ref[1] + scale_lat, 0.25)
        lat = np.arange(coords_ref[0] - scale_lat,coords_ref[0] + scale_lat, 0.25)
        coords_grid=np.zeros((len(lon) * len(lat), 2))

        coords_grid = [[lat[y],lon[x]] for x in range(len(lat)) for y in range(len(lon))]

        new_grid=coordinates_within_radius(coords_ref, coords_grid, radius)

        master_grid[i,j]=new_grid
```

Comment: Please try to make your example minimal following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: According to the error `master_grid` is not an array, it's a list.  At each step in your code you need to **know** the type of each variable.  Guesses don't count.

Comment: While probably not part of the problem, the `()` in `(new_grid)` don't do anything.  What are you trying to do with those?

Comment: @hpaulj, it was just a typo, thanks for calling that out.

Also, I will define `master_grid` as an array, thanks for helping here

Comment: You have not clearly indicated where the error comes from. I'm guessing it's not from the last line - that one should produce `IndexError: list index out of range` because `master_grid` appears only once before in your code: `master_grid=[]`. If I'm right, then switching to `master_grid` as an array won't help. Show the full traceback, then maybe somebody can help you.

Comment: Hi @rpoleski. I updated the code with a simplified version and the full traceback. The error is indeed the type of format apparently. Ideally, since I'm dealing with a multidimensional array, the final `master_grid` would be an array with the dimensions given by ``storm` and `date_time`. In addition, every cell of the array would have a nested array with the same shape of `new_grid` (size `lat` and `lon`).

Comment: The error message you posted is for current code (i.e., `master_grid[i,j]`), not the previous code (i.e., `master_grid[i][j]`). If you have posted error message that corresponds to code posted, you would have gotten the answer sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
master_grid = np.zeros((len(storm), len(date_time)))
```

instead of `master_grid=[]` should solve the problem.